# Почему на экран не выводится ничего?

Tags: php

```
class classWindow {

    private $width; 
    private $height;
    private $valueProfile =0;
    private $valueGlazing =0;
    private $baseValueWindow;
    private $area;
    private $perimetr;

    const transferToMetersQw =  1000000;
    const transferToMeters = 1000;

    public function __construct($width, $height, $valueglazing, $valueprofile) {
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->valueGlazing = $valueglazing;
        $this->valueProfile = $valueprofile;
    }

    public function getArea() {
        return $this->area;
    }
    public function getPerimetr() {
        return $this->perimetr;
    }

    private function calcArea() {
        $this->area = ($this->width * $this->height)/self::transferToMetersQw;
    }
    private function calcPerimetr() {
        $this->perimetr = (2*($this->width + $this->height))/ self::transferToMeters; 
    }    
}

$w = 1000; 
$h = 1000; 
$g = 200;
$s = 25;

$window1 = new classWindow($w, $h, $g, $s);

$area = $window1->getArea();



$perimetr = $window1->getPerimetr();




echo "<br>";
echo $area;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $perimetr;
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: если ничего не выводится - смотрите ошибки в логах, скорее всего все там. Это во-первых, а во-вторых - а что вы ожидаете увидеть? У вас скорее всего все вывелось, надо только посмотреть код страницы (там скорее всего будет несколько тегов `<br>` без какого-либо текста). У вас же методы `calcArea` и `calcPerimetr` ни где не вызываются, так что `getArea` и `getPerimetr` ничего не возвращают

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как вызвать эти методы внутри класса ? Если я допустим хочу чтобы поле area и поле perimetr получили результат вычисления метода calcArea и calcPerimetr соответсвенно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Или в конструкторе вызовите функции calcArea() и calcPerimetr():

```
public function __construct($width, $height, $valueglazing, $valueprofile) {
    $this->width = $width;
    $this->height = $height;
    $this->valueGlazing = $valueglazing;
    $this->valueProfile = $valueprofile;

    $this->calcArea();  //вычесления
    $this->calcPerimetr();  //вычесления
}
```

Или выполните эти функции перед получением значений:

```
$w = 1000; 
$h = 1000; 
$g = 200;
$s = 25;

$window1 = new classWindow($w, $h, $g, $s);

$window1->calcArea();  //вычесления
$window1->calcPerimetr();  //вычесления

$area = $window1->getArea();

$perimetr = $window1->getPerimetr();

echo "<br>";
echo $area;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $perimetr;
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: понял, спасибо вам огромное.

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной тогда отметьте ответ правильным, чтобы вопрос не остался актуальным